# How to get a size of all subvectors using std::acumulate?

Tags: c++, algorithm, qt, vector, c++14

I save a variable of type `QVector<QVector<MyKlass>>`, how I can get a number that would be a sum of subvector size using `std::accumulate`?

Using basic alorithms i can make the same:

```
for(QVector<MyKlass> &data: datas)
{
    m_countOfSamples+=data.size();
}
```

But how make it using stl?

Comment: did you try anything? why do you want `accumulate` when you already have it without?

Comment: The [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) function have an overload that takes a "binary op" argument, which is a callable object that will be used for the addition. You could provide a suitable [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) for it. Or keep using your loop which is quite clear.

Comment: stackoverflow is not a code writing service nor does it replace reading documentation and references. Did you encounter any problem while trying to write the code? THen please post a [mcve] of your code.

Comment: Honestly: You *could*, but it won't look better than your current range-based for loop...

Comment: You find an example on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think accumulate is not the best fit, but here is an example :

```
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> list_of_values
    {
        { 1, 2, 3},
        { 4,5 },
        { 6, 7, 8, 9 }
    };

    // with accumulate
    auto accumulated_sum = std::accumulate(list_of_values.begin(), list_of_values.end(), std::size_t{0ul},
        [](const auto& size, const auto& vec)
        {
            return size + vec.size();
        });

    std::cout << accumulated_sum << "\n";

    // simple range based for loop
    std::size_t sum{0ul};
    for (const auto& values : list_of_values) sum += values.size();
    std::cout << sum << "\n";

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: transform_reduce would be the better choice in this case, IMO, as it clearly separate both operations involved (getting the size and summing up these values. It might look like this:

auto reduction = std::transform_reduce(list_of_values.begin(), list_of_values.end(), std::size_t{0},std::plus<>{},[](auto const &sub_vec){return sub_vec.size();});